# R cran - non overlapping deciles

Tags: r, overlap, percentile

I need to paste the quartile number to a table, but it has to avoid overlapping values. An example would be:

```
table<-data.frame(num1=c(0,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,6), num2=seq(20,30,len=10))
```

if I use ntile from dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
table$cuartil<-ntile(table$num1, 4)
```

I get an overlapping result:

```
> table  
   num1     num2 cuartil
     0 20.00000       1
     1 21.11111       1
     1 22.22222       1
     2 23.33333       2
     2 24.44444       2
     3 25.55556       3
     3 26.66667       3
     3 27.77778       3
     3 28.88889       4
     6 30.00000       4
```

Instead of that I would need:

```
 num1   num2      cuartil
    0   20          1
    1   21.11111    1
    1   22.22222    1
    2   23.33333    2
    2   24.44444    2
    3   25.55556    3
    3   26.66667    3
    3   27.77778    3
    3   28.88889    3
    6   30          4
```

So the value 3 is only in one group and not in two (3 and 4).
Is there any other function to calculate percentiles but considering not to overlap values like ntile does?

Comment: @akrun. It was duplicated. I didn't see that.

Comment: @akrun, sorry. You are rigth. I though I was going to contaminate the site.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Also, dupe questions gets it easy to spot through googling.  If you can undelete the question, it will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just write your own function using `quantile()`:

```
quartile <- function(x) {
  qrt <- quantile(x)
  y <- x
  y[x<=qrt[5]] <- 4
  y[x<=qrt[4]] <- 3
  y[x<=qrt[3]] <- 2
  y[x<=qrt[2]] <- 1
  y[x<=qrt[1]] <- 0
  return(y)
}

table$cuartil <- quartile(table$num1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Sam's Function, a generic one might be:

```
quantG <- function(x, m) 
    {library(plyr)
    qrt <- quantile(x,probs=seq(0, 1, 1/m) )
    y <- x
    for (i in (1:5) ) {y[x<=qrt[m+2-i]] <- m+1-i}
    return(y)}
```

And:

```
table$cuartil <- quantG (table$num1,4)
```

gets the same result.